# LuaTeX gives weird output when using dev version of Fira Math

Tags: fonts, luatex, math-fonts

When using the dev version of Fira Math, LuaLaTeX gives weird output for integral, summation and other large operators:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{FiraMath-Regular.otf}[Path=./]  % Use local path
\begin{document}
\[ \int_0^1 dx + \sum_i + \prod_j \]
\end{document}
```

[image: lualatex-output]

However, when using XeLaTeX, everything goes well:

[image: xelatex-output]

So what's wrong with the font? Or with LuaTeX?

### Notes

- The font can be downloaded at [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/firamath/firamath/actions) as artifacts
- Which (incorrect) glyph will be used is not definite actually
- GitHub issue link: [firamath/firamath#67](https://github.com/firamath/firamath/issues/67)

Comment: Please note that the `minimal` class is not to be used for examples like this. Always use a class more similar to your actual document or use the `standalone` class.

Comment: The GitHub link seems wrong (it links to an issue about glyphsLib).

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Fixed

Comment: @daleif I use `minimal` to generate a cleaner dvi file to inspect, but anyway I have changed it to `article` for general purpose.

Comment: @stone-zeng A DVI file? 

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided